# Rest api to post documents, pictures in custom news feed web part

Tags: newsfeed, sharepoint-rest-api, social-feed

I have created custom web part for news feed.I can post text content through the rest API ,but I need to post images and documents through the rest API. I followed msdn blog also.In msdn blog text content post is only there. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Refer below link. It will clear Idea about Social attachment with rest api.[link](http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.in/2014/04/generate-sharepoint-2013-rest-code-with.html)